# WordPress rewrite rules for state and city

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, query-variable, template-include

I'm building a site where every state and city in the US has a landing page. I have a database of every city, state, and zip code, set up as a custom post type in WP. Here's what I've done successfully to create a landing page for every state:

```
function em_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['state/(.*)/?'] = 'index.php?state=$matches[1]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','em_rewrite_rules');

function em_query_vars($vars) {
    array_push($vars, 'state');
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars','em_query_vars');

function em_templates($template) {

    global $wp_query;
    if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['state'])) {
        return dirname(__FILE__) . '/single-state.php';
    }

    return $template;
}

add_filter('template_include', 'em_templates', 1, 1);
```

This is working great. Every page is dynamically generated based on the content in `single-state.php`.

Now I need to support cities, in the format:

`http://example.com/state/new-york/albany/`

I've found so many examples of different ways to create rewrite rules, but all of them follow a different format than what I already have. It took me many hours to get the working example above. Can someone propose a way I could achieve the URL format above and load a custom template when a city is specified?

Answer (score 3):

Wasn't as hard as I thought. Here's the working example, in case anyone finds it helpful:

```
function em_query_vars($vars) {
    array_push($vars, 'state');
    array_push($vars, 'city');
    return $vars;
}

add_filter('query_vars','em_query_vars');

function em_rewrite() {

    add_rewrite_rule( '^state/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?state=$matches[1]&city=$matches[2]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^state/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?state=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_tag('%state%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%city%','([^&]+)');

}

add_action('init', 'em_rewrite');

function em_templates($template) {

    global $wp_query;
    if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['state']) && isset($wp_query->query_vars['city'])) {
        return dirname(__FILE__) . '/single-city.php';
    } elseif (isset($wp_query->query_vars['state'])) {
        return dirname(__FILE__) . '/single-state.php';
    }

    return $template;
}

add_filter('template_include', 'em_templates', 1, 1);
```